# MerkleTree hashing keccak256 in golang is different with in js

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, keccak, hash-algorithm, merkleization

I am dealing with hashing keccak256 of address and amount to push to merkle tree in golang. I try to hash in js by using https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/merkle-tree lib and it is valid. but in golang is invalid. This code Golang, by using go-ethereum https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum:

```
addressTest := common.HexToAddress("0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
amountTest, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("5000000000000000000", 10)
leafData := append(
    addressTest.Bytes(),
    common.LeftPadBytes(amountTest.Bytes(), 32)...,
)
leaf := hexutil.Encode(crypto.Keccak256(leafData))
```

and the leaf value is different with other one in js with same data. Can anyone explain  the different and fix it to me ?